# Django doesn't want to show media files

Tags: python, django, media

I'm trying to output an image which i save like this:

```
product_image = models.ImageField(blank = True, upload_to='images')
```

My seetings.py looks like:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Also here is urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', include('store.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('store.urls')),

] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Query is like simple implemetation of ORM, but i tried it on ORM also

```
def index(request):
products = DAO.get_all_products()
return render(request, 'store/index.html', locals())
```

HTML:

```
<img src="{{product.product_image}}" class="img-responsive watch-right" alt=""/>
```

And it doesn't work, i don't see any image, and {{product.product_image}} shows me images/pic13.jpg in browser. But i can see this image in /admin
Error:

```
Not Found: /images/pic13.jpg
```

How to fix this issue? This page is situated is App called store, urls.py and settings.py are in main app

Comment: It is `{{ product.product_image.url }}`. Currently you are probably rendering the *path* of the file, not of the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We should **strongly** use ORM and queries into django models, django can't work with strings from database like with ImageField.

Answer (score 2):

You obtain the url through the [**`.url`** attribute [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.url):

```
<img src="{{ product.product_image.url }}" class="img-responsive watch-right" alt=""/>
```

Note that on production (so with `DEBUG = False` for example), Django does *not* serve files. In that case, you will need to configure nginx, apache, etc. For more information, see the [*Static file development view* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#static-file-development-view).

Comment: Actually I tried to use .url, but it also doesn't want to appear on the screen, the error has disappeared, but there is still no image

Comment: And if I try to output .url in browser it shows nothing, just emptiness.

Comment: @Emik: did you set `DEBUG = True` in the `settings.py`?

Comment: Yes, sure. Could you check it in my project? I think it's clear to understand, but i'm just new in it, so here is all this questions)
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iEilWllW-PuHLGL2ycRSv5bdN4tOWfBa/view?usp=sharing