# Hello coders i have a problem with showing the image in django and i don't know how to fix it and i'm just a begginer

Tags: django

Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/profile_pics/686319f4c9b83342a478a1a41561efbf.jpg
Using the URLconf defined in basic_project.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

[name='index']
admin/
basic_app/
The current path, media/profile_pics/686319f4c9b83342a478a1a41561efbf.jpg, didn't match any of these.

Comment: give more code so that we can try, it is running on your local system so we cannot see the entire error.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow - please review the [guidelines on how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: So it seems that you dont have a media/static files configured. People asked similar questions before so youmight consider checking these and then compare to find the error. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61901862/django-doesnt-want-to-show-media-files here is an example of such a question. One error might be that you dont have `MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')` in your settings file...

Answer (score 0):

By the error one can denote that django is not finding the given url, please post snippets of your urls.py